# PHP shell_exec - using RSYNC as root without password

Tags: php, root, rsync, shell-exec, sudoers

I'm trying to create a PHP web interface for a staging->production publishing script. The web interface is secure (intranet,passworded etc) so I am happy to for apache act as the root user to perform the rsync. There is no password for the root user, a keyfile is used for SSH access.

I have tried sudo-ing the rysnc command in the shell script...

```
sudo rsync --verbose --recursive --times --perms --links --delete /tmp/dir1/* /tmp/dir2/
```

And allowing apache to run rsync by adding the following to the sudoers file...

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
```

I am using PHP shell_exec to invoke the script...

```
$result = shell_exec('bash /tmp/syncscript.sh 2>&1');
```

I get the following error...

```
sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

How can I setup so I can run the rsync command as though I were the root user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try what i wrote in this post if you want to use SUDO from PHP. It solved all my problems and i have a similar setup to yours, i have a DEV server internally but i want it to do things that only root can...

[How to use exec() in php in combination with ssh 'hostname' command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671337/how-to-use-exec-in-php-in-combination-with-ssh-hostname-command/8671487#8671487)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the response - wasn't the approach I went for in the end, but was useful nonetheless. Will come back and vote you up when I get enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

In the end went for a non-sudo approach to this problem. Used [phpseclib](http://phpseclib) to get a connection to the box as a user that could do what I needed (not apache). And then made sure that the dirs/files that were being targetted in the rsync operation were accessible to this user.

Seems simple now I look back on it.